# Inner html add by ng-bind-html in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am generating bootstrap navigation menu by using angular directive. All of the things were Ok but when I reached finally to generate dropdown menu then I need to generate HTML dynamically. To generate HTML I have used angular ng-bind-html. The angular ng-bind-html is creating HTML very well. The ng-bind-html generating HTML looks like this.

```
<div ng-bind="getDropdownMenu(submenu)">
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

But I need only HTML looks like below no need this div ''.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
</ul>
```

To generate HTML I have used method looks like this.

```
$scope.getDropdownMenu = function (menu) {
  try {                
      var dropdownMenu = '<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">' +
      '<li><a href="#">Action</a></li>' +
      '<li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>' +
      '<li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>' +
      '<li class="divider"></li>' +
      '<li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>' +
      '<li class="divider"></li>' +
      '<li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>' +
       '</ul>';
        var trustedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(dropdownMenu);
            return trustedHtml;
        } catch (e) {
            throw e;
        }
    };
```

The full of bootstrap menu code is

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <div ng-bind-html="getDropdownMenu(submenu)"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So how can i remove That dive which is no need to me. Is there any way Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what your actual question is, but since you're generating HTML markup within your javascript function, you probably want [`ng-bind`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind) instead of `ng-bind-html`. The latter will escape the angle brackets.

Comment: Hi @Dan, yes I want to generate Inner HTML by this method getDropdownMenu(submenu). ng-bind supports string but I need HTML.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is... [Works HERE](http://plnkr.co/edit/tT2oLYQZXZoJvXgIFETv?p=preview)

Comment: I think that div is the least of what's wrong with your code... There's simpler ways to achieve what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create a custom directive

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tT2oLYQZXZoJvXgIFETv?p=preview)

```
app.directive('ngHtmlSafe',['$sce',function($sce){
  return {
    replace: true, /* don't use the parent element replace with your custom directive */
    template: 'template.html',
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      text: '='
    },
    link: function(scope,el, attrs){
      scope.safe = $sce.trustAsHtml(scope.text)

      /* copy all parent attributes from the element you added the directive to */
      for (var i=0; i < attrs.length; i++) {
         el.attr(attrs.item(i).nodeName, attrs.item(i).nodeValue);               
      }
    }
  }
}])
```

and add the directive to your element using `ul` instead of a `div`.

```
<ul ng-html-safe text="getDropdownMenu(submenu)"></ul>
```

Change your Controller to only include the `li`s

```
$scope.getDropdownMenu = function (menu) {
  try {                
      var dropdownMenu = '<li><a href="#">Action</a></li>' +
      '<li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>' +
      '<li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>' +
      '<li class="divider"></li>' +
      '<li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>' +
      '<li class="divider"></li>' +
      '<li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>';
        var trustedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(dropdownMenu);
            return trustedHtml;
        } catch (e) {
            throw e;
        }
    };
```

This will essentially replace the element you attach your directive to.  So there's probably a better way to make it more generic but this works for your use case.

Comment: No this is not working. In this way the method getDropdownMenu(submenu) returns only string. I have to tagged as a HTML.

Answer (score 0):

For HTML, you will need to bind to the property

Solution :

```
<div class="blog-post" [innerHtml]="testhtml"></div>
```

Note I moved the [innerHtml] to inside the div tag.

Leaving out the square brackets would bind to the attribute, so you would need to interpolate again