# ng-bind-html adds owns css class 'ng-binding' which brokes all nested css, how get rid of it?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-bind-html

I want to add some html to view from `$scope` variable. I want to add it inside angular-ui navbar. Generated code absolutely correct when I check it in a browser but it seems additional css style brokes everything.

My html looks like :

```
... navbar headers
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" ng-bind-html="menuHTML"></ul>
```

app.js is the following:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap','ngSanitize']);



myApp.controller('NavBarCtrl', function($scope, $http, $window,$sce) {

    $scope.isCollapsed = true;

    $scope.changeLanguage = function (language){
        console.log(language);
        var url = $window.location.href;
        if (url.indexOf('?') > -1){
            url = url.substr(0,url.indexOf("?"));
            url += '?language='+language;
        }else{
            url += '?language='+language;
        }
        $window.location.replace(url);
    };

    $http.get('headerMenu').success(function(res){
        console.log('header ok');
        $scope.headerMenuHTML =  $sce.trustAsHtml(res);
    });


});
```

Rendered page looks as expected but dropdown menu doesn't work. **When I copy not working html from browser and  manually  print it without `ng-bind-html` and remove `ng-binding` style everything is ok**.

How force ng-bind-html just add html without adding some extra css? The other way is creating own directive as [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25588816/inner-html-add-by-ng-bind-html-in-angularjs) but copipasted code doesn't work. Probably author of the question didn't show everything and thus I didn't include some important module, missed semicolon, made incorrect controller-directive declaration order(?) e.t.c

Could anybody tell me, how use ng-bind-html without its annoying extra css or provide correct own directive example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, problem was that inserted HTML contains angular-specific elements and thus I have to create special directive which compiles html after insertion.  [Working exapmle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22739144/2104560) on stackoverflow answers.